# Is there a way to apply OR to type bound in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, types

In Java we can apply only AND restriction to type bound like this:

```
public class <T extends Serializable & SomeThingDoable> MyClass{
    //...
}
```

But we could not tell Java to hold ***OR*** restriction.

Is it possible in Scala to provide a restrictions that it would be possible to add an element into a collection ***iff*** it's of type `SomeType1` ***OR*** `SomeType2`

Comment: do you plan to check using instanceof later?

Comment: @Ven pattern matching

Comment: okay, so instanceof. Works, so long you're aware of type erasure

Comment: @Ven Yes, I do, but what I want the compiler to ensure type safety...

Comment: Do you exhaustivity checking?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do that with guaranteeing type safety.

I mean, you could just do an `instance` and throw an error when the class is instantiated, but that's pretty dirty.

The much better solution is to use ADT (Abstract Data Types):

```
sealed trait NaturalNumber
final case class Zero() extends NaturalNumber
final case class Next(i: NaturalNumber) extends NaturalNumber


object Main extends App {
    val a: NaturalNumber = Next(Zero())
    a match {
        case Zero() => "zero"
    }
}
```

Which gives exhaustivity checking:

```
<console>:16: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using something like [coproducts](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#coproducts-and-discriminated-unions)

Also note that Dotty will have AND/OR built-in restrictions on types.

Answer (score 0):

there is no language level construct that supports this exactly, but as @dveim points out, i believe this is coming soon.

if you are asking with a specific practical use case in mind, you do have a few options though. you could use `Either[SomeType1, SomeType2]`, which has all of the constructs you need to represent this idea (but is not a type bound).

alternatively, you can achieve this effect using typeclasses:

```
sealed trait Or[T] {
  def someMethod(t: T): String
}

object Or {
  implicit object OrInt extends Or[Int] {
    def someMethod(t: Int): String = "int"
  }

  implicit object OrLong extends Or[Long] {
    def someMethod(t: Long): String = "long"
  }
}

object Test {

  import Or._

  def test[T](value: T)(implicit or: Or[T]): String =
    or.someMethod(value)

}
```

please excuse the trivial example, but what you get here is:

- a `sealed trait` which means, you can restrict others from adding more instances to the `Or` family (unless they can edit the actual file it's defined in)
- a well typed way to specify what functionality you want to have happen in the two different cases